# How do i recreate the starry night/shooting star animation on https://put.io homepage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

[Starry night effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp5fa.png)

I visited https://put.io and was impressed by the starry night animation used in their hero section on it's homepage and was wondering out of curiosity, if they used an already existing JavaScript library and how the animation was achieved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Glad you liked it. It was made by our friend [Ates Goral](https://magnetiq.ca/). You can find an infinitely customizable version [here](https://atesgoral.github.io/put.io.starry.night/) and the code at [GitHub](https://github.com/atesgoral/put.io.starry.night).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really helpful.